# How to track User Properties on a web app with the Facebook Analytics Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-analytics

I've been reading the Facebook Docs on the new Web Tracking of Facebook Analytics but couldn't find anything about how to track User Properties in Web with the JavaScript SDK.

If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

User properties are currently only supported in the iOS and Android SDKs.